# web framework, .. Spring, dropwizard thread pooling and DI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, dropwizard

I wanted to understand thread pool operation in web framework . I saw this behavior with Dropwizard, (Spring behavior is also the same).
Say we have defined a resource..

```
@Path("/id/create") 
CreateResource { ...
```

then..e.g. for Integration Testing  we have

```
Thread T1, T2, T3 T4
foreach: Thread // 1 to 4
Call above resource...
```

My expectation was that each call to the resource would take a thread from the Thread pool and instantiate a new "CreateResource" object. However each call to the resource is on a different Thread form the ThreadPool, as expected. However, I see that the "CreateResource" is the same object in each of the 4 API calls. i.e. There is only 1 instance of "CreateResource".

why is that so ?

Where can i find more information about this behavior ?

Comment: Because the frameword chose to design it that way. Can't talk for DropWizard, but Spring beans are singletons by default. Which makes sense, since most controllers (and other beans) should be stateless anyway (except for references to other beans initialised at startup). http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes

Comment: this is a good place to start... thanks !!